# How can I run a coffeescript method that depends on the js event while maintaining DRY code?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, dom-events, dry

I want to DRY up this code:

```
@$canvas.on 'mousemove', (e) =>
  return unless @running
  @mouseTarget.set @board.x + e.clientX, @board.y + e.clientY * 2
  @player?.mouseMove()

@$canvas.on 'mousedown', (e) =>
  return unless @running
  @mouseTarget.set @board.x + e.clientX, @board.y + e.clientY * 2
  @player?.mouseDown()

@$canvas.on 'mouseup', (e) =>
  return unless @running
  @mouseTarget.set @board.x + e.clientX, @board.y + e.clientY * 2
  @player?.mouseUp()
```

I want to having something to the effect of:

```
@$canvas.on 'mousemove', 'mousedown', 'mouseup' -> @mouseAction

mouseAction: (e) =>
  return unless @running
  @mouseTarget.set @board.x + e.clientX, @board.y + e.clientY * 2
  @player?.mouseUp() # here is the problem...
```

The thing is, how do I alternate between `@player?.mouseUp()`, `@player?.mouseDown()` and `@player?.mouseMove()` while maintaining DRY code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on pdoherty926's answer, you want to somehow do the same thing, but invoke different methods on `@player`. If you control the method names and you can always use the event type, you can do what pdoherty926 suggests -- otherwise, here's a suggestion for a more explicit solution:

```
@$canvas.on 'mousemove', @mouseAction 'mouseMove'
@$canvas.on 'mousedown', @mouseAction 'mouseDown'
@$canvas.on 'mouseup', @mouseAction 'mouseUp'

mouseAction: (action) =>
  (e) =>
   return unless @running
   @mouseTarget.set @board.x + e.clientX, @board.y + e.clientY * 2
   @player?[action]()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
capitaliseFirstLetter = (string) -> string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)
# you could also include the underscore.string library and use _.capitalize

event_type = "mouse#{capitaliseFirstLetter(e.type.split('mouse')[1])}"
@player[event_type]()
```